# Bug: <kbd> causing text overflow and cutoff on mobile site?

Tags: bug, answers, formatting

I just came across [an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/40999/13197) that is overflowing my screen and is cutoff. It was fine before a recent edit in which the poster used the `<kbd>` formatting to markup some instructions. I suspect that the culprit is the `<kbd>` formatting. Also, the vote counter has been pushed over to the left. Here is a screenshot of the bug (left) next to the properly formatted question post (right):

[image] vs [image]